# Trouble Implementing BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write an Windows Forms application in VB.NET that unzips some files form a directory and uploads them to a server. My problem is that the application keeps locking up on me and going into "Not Responding" mode. I did some reading and determined that I needed to use some type of multi-threading. I read about the BackgroundWorker and started trying to implement it. I am having some trouble getting it working right. I have a few time comsuming processes running in the the Sub named ProcessFiles. This is where I was trying to implement the BackgroundWorker. I was planning on using multiple BackgroundWorkers since I have multiple time consuming processes. I also want to display status messages on the screen and tried to do that using the ReportProgress, but was unable to get that working as well. There is also a timer that ticks at certain intervals checking to see if new .zip files have been put into the directory for pickup. I have posted my code below. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1

Private bw1 As BackgroundWorker    
Private de1 As AutoResetEvent

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub   

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        Me.btnStart.Enabled = False
        Me.btnStop.Enabled = True

        'Go ahead and manually tick the timer right off the bat to start checking for files

        Timer1_Tick(Me, e)

        'Once the first tick has occurred, start the timer if needed
        If Timer1.Enabled = False Then
            WriteToFile("Timer started")
            'Timer1.Start()
        End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnChooseZipFileLoc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChooseZipFileLoc.Click
    Me.fbdZipFileLocation.ShowDialog()

    Me.txtZipFileLoc.Text = Me.fbdZipFileLocation.SelectedPath
End Sub

Private Sub btnChooseExtractToLoc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChooseExtractToLoc.Click
    Me.fbdExtractTo.ShowDialog()

    Me.txtExtractToLoc.Text = Me.fbdExtractTo.SelectedPath
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    Me.btnStart.Enabled = True
    Me.btnStop.Enabled = False       

    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub    

Private Sub ProcessFiles()
    Dim creationTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now        
    Dim LinuxDestinationPath As String = "\\IMMTerSrv\Bit_Stmts\Test"        
    Dim LinuxFileCount As Integer
    Dim ZipFileTempFolderPath As String = String.Empty
    Dim PDFCopyFileCount As Integer = 0
    Dim XMLCopyFileCount As Integer = 0

        bw1 = New BackgroundWorker()
        bw1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        bw1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        AddHandler bw1.DoWork, AddressOf bw1_DoWork
        AddHandler bw1.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw1_ProgressChanged
        AddHandler bw1.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw1_RunWorkerCompleted
        de1 = New AutoResetEvent(False)           

        ZipFileTempFolderPath = Me.txtZipFileLoc.Text.TrimEnd("\") + "\ZipFileTemp"

        'If ZipFileTemp folder does not exist, create it and copy all .zip files into it
        'Files will only get copied in once that way.
        'Once a file is complete, it will be moved out into the complete folder
        'This provides a way to keep up with which files have been finished and and which ones have not
        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(ZipFileTempFolderPath) = False Then

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ZipFileTempFolderPath)

            Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(Me.txtZipFileLoc.Text)

            For Each zipfi In di.GetFiles
                'If the zip file is not already there, then copy it
                If File.Exists(ZipFileTempFolderPath.TrimEnd("\") + "\" + zipfi.Name) = False Then
                    System.IO.File.Copy(zipfi.FullName, ZipFileTempFolderPath.TrimEnd("\") + "\" + zipfi.Name)
                End If
            Next
        End If

        Dim diZipFileTemp As New DirectoryInfo(ZipFileTempFolderPath)

        'This gets all files with the oldest created being first
        Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = diZipFileTemp.GetFiles().OrderBy(Function(fi) fi.CreationTime).ToArray()

        Dim fri As FileInfo

        'This begins the process looping thru each .zip file
        For Each fri In fiArr

            'Before we start processing a new file, we need to check the 
            'time of day to see if we should proceed to the next file or not
            If DetermineFileProcessStatus() = True Then 'If the function returns true, then continue processing the file. Otherwise, do no process.

                'Get the single oldest .zip file
                'Build string location                    

                Dim CopyZipFilesFrom As String = Me.txtExtractToLoc.Text.TrimEnd("\") + "\" + Strings.Left(fri.Name, fri.Name.Length - 4)

                'Only get .zip files
                If fri.Extension = ".zip" Then

                    'Unzip files
                    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(CopyZipFilesFrom) = False Then

                        If Not bw1.IsBusy Then
                            bw1.RunWorkerAsync(fri)
                            de1.WaitOne()

                        End If


                    End If                

                End If
                'The unzip process has ended

                'Dim diUZ As New DirectoryInfo(CopyZipFilesFrom.TrimEnd("\") + "\" + Strings.Left(fri.Name, fri.Name.Length - 4))

                'Reset file counts
                PDFCopyFileCount = 0
                XMLCopyFileCount = 0

                Dim diUZ As New DirectoryInfo(CopyZipFilesFrom)

                'Copy all .pdf files first
                For Each fiUZ In diUZ.GetFiles("*.pdf")

                    fiUZ.MoveTo(LinuxDestinationPath + fiUZ.Name)

                    PDFCopyFileCount += 1                   

                Next             

                'Next copy all .xml files
                For Each fiUZ In diUZ.GetFiles("*.xml")                  

                    fiUZ.MoveTo(LinuxDestinationPath + fiUZ.Name)

                    XMLCopyFileCount += 1

                Next

                'Once all of the files have been moved into Linux for archiving, we can
                'delete the zip file from the temp directory. This will allow the user to know which files have been completed all the way through in case
                'the program crashes.
                Dim ZipFileCompletePath As String = Me.txtZipFileLoc.Text.TrimEnd("\") + "\" + "ZipFileComplete"

                If System.IO.Directory.Exists(ZipFileCompletePath) = False Then
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ZipFileCompletePath)
                End If

                fri.MoveTo(ZipFileCompletePath + "\" + fri.Name)

                'Now that all files have been copied from the .zip file, we need to wait until there are less than or equal to 500 files in the linux directory
                'before another mass copy is started. Even though these files have been copied into the directory, they still all need to process and this can take
                'a couple of additional hours to do.
                Do
                    LinuxFileCount = Directory.GetFiles(LinuxDestinationPath).Count()              

                    Loop Until LinuxFileCount <= 500
            Else
                    Exit Sub
            End If
        Next fri

        Timer1.Stop()
        'Close the program because everything has completed
        Me.Close()


End Sub


Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        If DetermineFileProcessStatus() = True Then

            If Timer1.Enabled = True Then

                Timer1.Stop()
            End If

            ProcessFiles()

            Timer1.Start()

        End If


End Sub


Private Function DetermineFileProcessStatus() As Boolean

    Select Case DateTime.Now.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString
            Case "Saturday"
                If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= New TimeSpan(13, 0, 0) Then

                    Return True
                Else

                    Return False
                End If
            Case "Sunday"
                If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= New TimeSpan(22, 0, 0) Then
                    'ProcessFiles()
                    Return True
                Else

                    Return False
                End If
            Case Else 'Monday thru Friday
                If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= New TimeSpan(9, 0, 0) AndAlso DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= New TimeSpan(22, 0, 0) Then
                    'If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= New TimeSpan(14, 0, 0) AndAlso DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= New TimeSpan(22, 0, 0) Then

                    Return True
                Else
                    Select Case DateTime.Now.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString
                        Case "Friday"
                            If DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < New TimeSpan(14, 0, 0) Then 'It is Friday before 14:00
                            Else 'Since it has gotten to this point it must be a Friday between 22:00:01 and 23:59:59
                            End If
                        Case Else
                    End Select
                    Return False
                End If
        End Select

End Function

'Public Delegate Sub SetLabelTextDelegate(ByVal LabelObject As Label, ByVal Value As String)

'Public Sub SetLabelText(ByVal LabelObject As Label, ByVal Value As String)
'    Try

'        If LabelObject.InvokeRequired Then
'            Dim dlg As New SetLabelTextDelegate(AddressOf SetLabelText)
'            dlg.Invoke(LabelObject, Value)
'        Else
'            LabelObject.Text = Value
'        End If

'    Catch ex As Exception
'        Throw ex
'    End Try

'End Sub

Private Sub setLabelText(ByVal text As String)
    bw1.ReportProgress(0, text) 'You can write any int as first argument as far as will not be used anyway
End Sub


Private Sub bw1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Me.lblStatus.Text = e.UserState
    Me.lblStatus.Update()
End Sub

Private Sub bw1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    Try
        If e.Cancel = False Then
            Dim fi As System.IO.FileInfo
            fi = e.Argument
            If IsNothing(fi) = False Then
                bw1.ReportProgress(0, "Testing....")
                UnzipFile(fi.FullName)
                e.Result = fi.FullName
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        de1.Set()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub UnzipFile(ByVal ZipFileFullName As String)
    'setLabelText("File " + ZipFileFullName + " is in the process of unzipping!")
    'bw1.ReportProgress(0, "File " + ZipFileFullName + " is in the process of unzipping!")
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(ZipFileFullName, Me.txtExtractToLoc.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub bw1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim ZipFileFullName As String

    ZipFileFullName = e.Result

    'setLabelText(lblStatus, ZipFileFullName + " has been unzipped successfully!")

End Sub'
```

Comment: We always ask people to post a piece of their code! Let me start reading. Will be back hopefully tonight :)

Comment: OK. What's wrong here? An exception? Or unintended behavior?

Comment: I was under the impression that using a BackgroundWorker would allow the user to interact with the form (which is not the case with what I have now). Also can't get it to display any status messages to the screen.

Comment: Pretty much all your code from `ProcessFiles` should be in `bw1_DoWork`

Comment: Can I just call the 'ProcessFiles' sub from 'bw1_DoWork'?

Comment: I'm writing a long answer. And BTW I owe you an apology. I put my first comment on the phone, and now that I'm on the PC, your code doesn't seem that long :)

Comment: @zstutts82, yes, in theory you can call `ProcessFiles` from the `DoWork` event handler.  The rules for using a `BackgroundWorker` are simple and should be kept in mind whenever writing code to use one.  The point of the `BackgroundWorker` is that the `DoWork` event is raised on a secondary thread while the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events are raised on the UI thread. You need to first identify what your long-running process is and put its code in the `DoWork` event handler or a method called from it...

Comment: ...If you need to update the UI during the background process, you call `ReportProgress` and update the UI in the `ProgressChanged` event handler.  If you need to update the UI when the background process is finished then you do so in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler. If `ProcessFiles` contains your code for the long-running process and you're executing it on the UI thread then obviously the UI will not be responsive and you have not used the `BackgroundWorker` as intended.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that's not 100% true, what you said; "If you need to update the UI during the background process, you call ReportProgress and update the UI in the ProgressChanged event handler". You can but that call is for returning progress of a long running process, using a delegate properly will update UI if done correctly and should be used.

Comment: Hence, that's why it's called ReportProgress...

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR, given that the whole point of the `BackgroundWorker` is to allow you to use methods and events in a familiar way instead of messing with delegates and invocations, updating the UI during the background process IS reporting progress.  There's no strict definition of reporting progress that states that it is only updating a `ProgressBar` or displaying a percentage. If you're going to use delegates and invocations then why bother with the `BackgroundWorker` in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the all of the suggestions. I am going to try them to see what I can come up with.

Comment: Thanks to all who commented on this. I was able to get my code working by putting everything all of the ProcessWork code into DoWork. I also got ReportProgress working like it should be.